# Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Prove that $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.
>   $$\{a_n\} = \frac{n^2-5n+6}{n^2+n+1}\:\forall n\in\mathbb{Z_+}$$

I know $\{a_n\}$ approaches $1$ when n goes to $\infty$. I tried to prove it using limit definition.
$$\forall\epsilon > 0\:\exists N>0\:\: s.t \:\:n>N \implies \left|\frac{n^2-5n+6}{n^2+n+1} - 1\right|<\epsilon$$
Next I tried to find $N$.
$$\left|\frac{n^2-5n+6}{n^2+n+1} - 1\right| = \left|\frac{-6n+5}{n^2+n+1}\right|<\epsilon$$
But I couldn't find $N$ using above inequality. I ended up with an inequality of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $6n-5<6n$, and $n^2 +n + 1 \geq n^2 \ \forall \ n >1 $. So the inequality you have is 
$$
\bigg|\frac{1}{n} \bigg| < \frac{\varepsilon}{6}
$$
which is true $\forall n >\frac{6}{\varepsilon}$, so if you set $\varepsilon = 1, n_0 =6$, then $\forall n>6$ the inequality you have is within $\varepsilon=1$ from the limit

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be large enough so that $\frac{6}{N} < \epsilon$. Then for $n \geq N$:
$$
\frac{|-6n + 5|}{|n^2 + n + 1|} = \frac{6n - 5}{n^2 + n + 1} \leq \frac{6n}{n^2} < \epsilon
$$